# Simple accordion menu (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

**jQuery:**

```
// ACCORDION
$('.accordion .answer').hide(); // hide all
$('.accordion .question').click(function(){
     $('.accordion .answer').slideUp(); // hide all open
     $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown(); // show the anwser
     return false;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt class="question">question</dt>
    <dd class="answer">answer</dd>
    <dt class="question">question</dt>
    <dd class="answer">answer</dd>
</dl>
```

... works, but

- The 'active' class must be removed from inactive question elements &
- At least one of the answers remains open; all answers should be able to close.

Thanks!

Comment: Wheel reinvention? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: Don't want to load 50+ kb of js for widgets and animations, just need a basic accordion.

Comment: It's 15kb for the Accordion and its dependencies (disregarding jQuery itself because you are using that anyway), not 50.

Comment: Okay, but still 15kb is a lot if only I need is a simple accordion. I figured it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it:

```
$('.accordion .answer').hide(); // hide all
$(".accordion .question").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next(".answer").slideToggle(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.accordion .answer').hide(); // hide all
$('.accordion .question').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    } else {
        $('.accordion .answer').removeClass('active').slideUp();
        $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown();
    }
    return false;
});
```

But you should really take a look at the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion).

Comment: Almost works! But 1) it allows opening multiple answers and 2) if you open first and then the second, both retain the 'active' class.

Comment: You are absolutely right, a minor bug(forgot a dot(.)) and a flaw in my thinking(forgot to slide up inactives). Should work now, but I see you figured it out yourself. :)